# Delete some rows in dataframe based on condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe as follows:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| aa | 0 |
| aa | 0 |
| aa | 1 |
| aa | 0 |
| aa | 0 |
| bb | 0 |
| bb | 0 |
| bb | 1 |
| bb | 0 |
| bb | 0 |
| bb | 0 |

I want to delete all rows of the dataframe when there is 1 appeared in column 'value' with relation to 'name' column.

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| aa | 0 |
| aa | 0 |
| aa | 1 |
| bb | 0 |
| bb | 0 |
| bb | 1 |

What is the best way to do so? I thought about pd.groupby method and use some conditions inside, but cannot understand how to make it work.

Comment: So you want to delete all rows after the first 1 for each name?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Are there some edge cases? Is it only 0 or 1? What have you tried?

Comment: No, there are no any other tricky cases. Only 0 and 1. I think it is possible to solve in a simple way without writing any search algorithm. Maybe iterating each row of a dataframe and looking for 1 then stop and move to another name.

Comment: How many names are in your dataset?

Comment: 132 different names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most beautiful of ways to do it but this should work.

```
df = df.loc[df['value'].groupby(df['name']).cumsum().groupby(df['name']).cumsum() <=1]
```

Comment: Tried you solution and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach on solving this.

```
# Imports.
import pandas as pd

# Creating a DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'aa', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'aa', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'aa', 'value': 1},
                   {'name': 'aa', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'aa', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'bb', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'bb', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'bb', 'value': 1},
                   {'name': 'bb', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'bb', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'bb', 'value': 0},
                   {'name': 'bb', 'value': 0}])
# Filtering the DataFrame.
df_filtered = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x[x.index <= x['value'].idxmax()]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This looks much more clean than what I came up with.